# How to perform the default link action after the specified action with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a "slide out" div that I'm hiding/showing via CSS positioning, and using jquery to toggle a class that sets the hidden/shown state of the div.

That's all working great.  What I'm now trying to do is have any link farther up on the page change the class to show the div, and jump down the page to it.

Here's what I have :

```
$('a[href="#request-trial"]').click(function () {
  $("#request-trial").toggleClass("on off");
});
```

The problem is it's first jumping to the anchor, and then changing the class, so it's jumping to the position of the div when it's "off" instead of when it's "on" - does that make sense?  Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

adding some extra info:

HTML:

```
<section class="form-popup on" id="request-trial">
<div class="container">
<h1>Let's Talk more!</h1>
<p>Have a project in mind or have an organizational challenge you need assistance in tackling? Get in touch... we’ll discuss ways that the Beyond Nines team could help.</p>

<a class="close">Close</a>
</div>
</section>
```

Link is something like:

```
<a href="#request-trial">Sign up</a>
```

Css:

```
.form-popup,
.form-popup.on {
position: absolute;
height: 500px;
z-index: 0;
bottom: 0px;
opacity: 1;
 }

 .form-popup.off {

 bottom: -580px;
 opacity: 0;

  }
```

Comment: The class is probably changing beforehand, but the slide animation takes a non zero amount of time to complete. Please post your HTML, so a solution to the problem can be attempted.

Comment: you are probably right - is there any way to delay it?

Comment: @user1851361 i think my answer is what you are looking for:http://jsfiddle.net/Ag98N/

Comment: Having another thought about this - could it be because it's positioned from the bottom?  maybe it's jumping to the bottom of the div? and not the .off position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code

```
$('a[href="#request-trial"]').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var target = $("#request-trial");
  target.toggleClass("on off");
  if (target.length > 0 && target.hasClass("on"))
  {
     $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: target.offset().top - $(window).height()
     }, 500);
  } 
});
```

Comment: so if the `#request-trial` has the class `"on off"` then you want to jump to this `#request-trial`, or I miss something?

Comment: ah - ok, i see what's happening - i really just want it to jump to if the class is "on" - changed that in your code, but it's still jumping to the bottom of my div instead of the top. Could this be because it's positioned from the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ag98N/2/

```
var documentBody = (($.browser.chrome)||($.browser.safari)) ? document.body : document.documentElement;
      $('a[href="#request-trial"]').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var $targetElem = $("#request-trial")
         $targetElem.toggleClass("on off");
          if($targetElem.is('.on'))
         $(documentBody).animate({scrollTop: $targetElem.offset().top}, 50);
      });
```

Comment: this jumps to the original .off position - same as my original code

Comment: Thanks, but still not working - it must have something to do with the positioning - I tried setting the #request-trial in your jsfiddle and it stopped working, same result on my site.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag98N/5/  If no, you should really be more specific about your problem, i cannot understand it